# Getting the error "com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: GC overhead limit exceeded" while building an app in sencha cmd v6.5.1.240

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am not able to build my extjs app using sencha command "sencha app build"

I have recently updated my sencha cmd version to Cmd v6.5.1.240 and extjs version to ext-6.5.0. I also tried updating the environmental variable, by updating the path variable "set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"", but couldn't resolve the issue.

The screen shot is also attached. Please help me in resolving this problem.

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Not sure why, but I started getting this issue suddenly, and the options you suggested helped fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You suggestion was correct, but the location was not. 
You can change the vmoptions in the Sencha CMD directory:

> userhome/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.1.240/

There should be a file called sencha.vmoptions.
Just add your memory increase there.

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue, but updating in *sencha.vmoptions* did not help for me.
Version Sencha cmd (6.5.3.6) on Windows 10.
So I had to set in command line before sencha build (sencha app build):

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Answer (score 0):

From sencha 6.6+, this command is enough:

macos : `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms2048m -Xmx8192m -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true`

window: `set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms2048m -Xmx8192m -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true`